# Can Openebs iSCSI target to run on same node as POD attached to the PV?

Tags: openebs

Any way to force  OpenEBS iscsi target to run on same node as POD attached to the PV?
See below scenario:
NODE A: POD + PV mounted +  openebs replica
NODE B:  openebs replica +  iscsi target

traffic then goes from nodeA to nodeB(iscsi target)--NodeB(write to disk) -- nodeA(write to disk)

and then if try to read a file always generate traffic from nodeA to nodeB when nodeA have a full replica so can be read from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using Target Affinity Policy. Policy can be used to co-locate volume target pod on the same node as workload.

```
labels:
  openebs.io/target-affinity: <application-unique-label>
```

You can specify the Target Affinity in both application and OpenEBS PVC using the following way

For Application Pod, it will be similar to the following

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: fio-cstor
  labels:
    name: fio-cstor
    openebs.io/target-affinity: fio-cstor
```

For OpenEBS PVC, it will be similar to the following.

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: fio-cstor-claim
  labels:
    openebs.io/target-affinity: fio-cstor
```

Note: This feature works only for cases where there is a 1-1 mapping between a application and PVC. It's not recommended for STS where PVC is specified as a template.